# How to disable server side ajax hit during sorting in data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatables

While sorting header tags ajax call is occuring how to restrict the ajax call. I don't want server side sorting. I need client side sorting. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**:

```
function InitUserTable(params){
       var clientListTable= $('#clientListTable').dataTable( { 
    "bLengthChange" : false,
     "iDisplayLength" : 10,
     "bSort" : true,
     "bFilter": false,
     "bDestroy":true,
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "bProcessing": true,
     "bServerSide": true, 
     "bAutoWidth" : false,
                "sAjaxSource": "../clients/clientDataTable.do?"+params,
                "fnDrawCallback": function(){
                     $("#clientListTable tbody tr").click( function( e ) {

                            if ( $(this).hasClass('datatablerowhighlight') ) {
                                $(this).removeClass('datatablerowhighlight');
                            }
                            else {
                                clientListTable.$('tr.datatablerowhighlight').removeClass('datatablerowhighlight');
                                $(this).addClass('datatablerowhighlight');
                            }

                     });
                      }, 
                "aoColumns": [
                                      { "sTitle": "#",   "mData": "index", "sClass": "center"  },
                                      { "sTitle": "Client Name",   "sortable":true ,"mData": "clientName", "sClass": "left" ,"fnRender": function(obj) {
                                          var clientName = obj.aData.clientName;
                                          var clientId  = obj.aData.clientId;
                                          var index= obj.aData.index;
                                          var viewClient="";
                                          viewClient = "<div style='cursor:pointer;width:125px;' class='ellipsis'><u onclick='javascript:showClientInfo(\""+clientId+"\" ,\""+clientName+ "\" , \""+index+"\",this);'>"+ clientName +" </u></div>";
                                          return viewClient;
                                      } },

                                      { "sTitle": "Business Type",   "mData": "businessType", "sClass": "left" ,"fnRender": function(obj) {
                                          var businessType = obj.aData.businessType;
                                          return "<div style='width:150px;' class='ellipsis'>"+ businessType +"</div>"

                                      } }
                            ]
         } );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is related to DataTable.so first load json data using "sAjaxSource" and once your data get loaded,grab the settings object (fnSettings()) and set sAjaxSource 
or you can use fnServerData to intercept the first call and then do what you want

Comment: And for client side sorting u can use sort() with objects Eg. var data = ["B", "O", "A", "M"];
data.sort(); 
Output: A,B,M,O

Answer (score 0):

make the bServerSide as false. It will not go serverside for sorting